# How to set app: backgroundTint using Android Databinding LiveData

Tags: android

`val inputUnderLineColor = MutableLiveData(R.color.red2)`

`app:backgroundTint="@{viewModel.inputUnderLineColor}"`

I want to set the EditText UnderLine color value depending on the state, but I get the following error

`Cannot find a setter for <android.widget.EditText app:backgroundTint> that accepts parameter type 'androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData<java.lang.Integer>'`

How do you solve this ??

Comment: I think you need to unwrap the value in MutableLiveData, tried with this? `@{viewModel.inputUnderLineColor.value}`

Comment: `R.color.red2` is not Color itself its a resource id of color resource ..

Comment: @ADM how can I set the BackgroundTint ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it like below `ContextCompat.getColor()`

```
 <layout>
         <data>
                <import type="android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat"/>
                <variable name="viewModel" type="com.example.myapp.yourObject" />
            </data>
        ...
         <EditText 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@{data.text}"
                android:textColor="@{ContextCompat.getColor(context, viewModel.inputUnderLineColor)}" />
    </layout>
```

**1.**  Make sure to import ContextCompat as shown above.

**2.**  You can automagically 'context' as a method parameter for ContextCompat.getColor() because it will be automatically resolved to the view's context.

Comment: I am wondering how to set BackgroundTint using DataBinding, not how to use DataBinding

Comment: This worked for me and the problem was that `@ColorRes` and `@ColorInt` Annotation were confusing me, but now I realize. Thank you !

Comment: Anytime Welcome :) Can you please upvote my answer!